# Error: MIME type ('application/json') is not executable, and strict MIME type checking is enabled with YQL statements?

Tags: javascript, jquery, json, yql

I was trying to run an example about [YQL from Yahoo](https://developer.yahoo.com/yql/guide/yql-tutorials.html). This is the code that I am supposed to use:

```
<body>
<div id='results'></div>
<script src='https://query.yahooapis.com/v1/public/yql?q=select%20*%20from%20rss%20where%20url%3D%22http%3A%2F%2Frss.news.yahoo.com%2Frss%2Ftopstories%22&format=json&diagnostics=true&callback='></script>
</body>
<script type='text/javascript'>
function top_stories(o){
  var items = o.query.results.item;
  var output = '';
  var no_items=items.length;
  for(var i=0;i<no_items;i++){
    var title = items[i].title;
    var link = items[i].link;
    var desc = items[i].description;
    output += "<h3><a href='" + link + "'>"+title+"</a></h3>" + desc + "<hr/>";
  }
  document.getElementById('results').innerHTML = output;  
}
</script>
```

I have read other question with same error and most of them give an answer similar to this one

> By adding a callback argument, you are telling jQuery that you want to make a request for JSONP using a script element instead of a request for JSON using XMLHttpRequest.
>   JSONP is not JSON. It is a JavaScript program.

My problem is I am using JavaScript and I can't find the code in above script where I am expecting JSONP. I am a complete newbiw so may be I have made a silly mistake. What is wrong with the code above? Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `<script>` element on line 3 is requesting the JSONP. It's just hard coded to do it instead of being added with JS (which would be normal for JSONP).

YQL is delivering JSON because you've said `callback=` and then stopped without actually providing a callback function name.

Comment: So, I should just remove `callback=`?

Comment: Removing `callback=` entirely will also fail to provide a callback name, so YQL will continue to deliver JSON instead of JSONP. If you want JSONP then you have to give it a callback name. If you want JSON then you can't load it using a `<script>` element's `src`.

Comment: But it says `format=json` and not `format=jsonp` so how am I requesting JSONP. I am sorry I am confused.

Comment: How does the same code works in YQL console? Yahoo have this statement on the tutorial page `Notice that the YQL statement has been URL-encoded and the format parameter specifies that the response be in JSON.` Could you please provide a code example?

Comment: 1. You're making a request for a URL. 2. You're doing this with a `<script>` element's `src`. 3. JSON is a data format, not a program so you can't set the `src` of a `<script>` to point to JSON. 4. JSONP is a JavaScript program that does nothing but call a function and passes it some data in an argument. 5. The name of that function is traditionally specified using the `callback` query string value. 6. Since you haven't specified one, you are getting back JSON, which is not a JavaScript program, which errors because a `<script>` expects one. 7. If you specify a callback you get JS.

Comment: "How does the same code works in YQL console?" — Because the YQL console is not a `<script>` element's `src` so it isn't expecting to get the data returned in the form of a JavaScript program.

Comment: *But it says format=json and not format=jsonp* — Blame YQL. It switches to JSONP if you add a callback query string value.

Comment: "Could you please provide a code example?" — There's a complete example in the documentation you linked to in the first place. You seem to have got half way through the tutorial and stopped.

Comment: Thanks, your comment above cleared things up :). I got it working now.